# MS SQL Invalid Column Name

Tags: sql-server

Getting an "Invalid Column Name" error when including the following in my PHP MSSQL Select statement ...

```
IIf([PD_Mill_Start].[Job Name] Like '%glass%' Or [PD_Mill_Start].[Job Name] Like '%hinge%' Or [PD_Mill_Start].[Job Name] Like '%weather%' Or [PD_Mill_Start].[Job Name] Like '%molding%' Or [PD_Mill_Start].[Style] Like '%N/A%' Or [PD_Mill_Start].[Interior or Exterior] Like '%other%',[Batch Door Count],0) AS [Del Other Qty],
```

The whole Select statement is as follows in case it helps ...

```
SELECT PD_Mill_Start.[Order Number], PD_Mill_Start.[Job Name], PD_Mill_Start.[Mill Start], PD_Mill_Start.[Mill Start] AS [Mill Start To Min], PD_Mill_Start.[Date Shipped], PD_Mill_Start.[Stain Grade/Paint Grade] AS Grade, PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Ship To Verified], PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Mill Start Sent Date], IIf([Date Shipped] Is Not Null,[Date Shipped],IIf([PD_Delivery_Schedule].[Departure Date] Is Not Null,[PD_Delivery_Schedule].[Departure Date],IIf([PD_Mill_Start].[Promised Date] Is Not Null,[PD_Mill_Start].[Promised Date],' '))) AS [Forecast Date], PD_Mill_Start.[Date Entered], PD_Mill_Start.[Promised Date], PD_Mill_Start.Style, PD_Mill_Start.[Batch Door Count], PD_Mill_Start.[Batch Jamb Count], PD_Mill_Start.[Interior or Exterior], IIf(SUBSTRING([PD_Mill_Start].[Interior or Exterior],1,1) Like '%i%','Interior',IIf(SUBSTRING([PD_Mill_Start].[Interior or Exterior],1,1) Like '%e%','Exterior','UnKnown')) AS [Rpt Int or Ext], PD_Mill_Start.Status, PD_Delivery_Schedule.Driver, PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Departure Date], PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Departure Time], PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Delivery Sequence], PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Delivery Date/Time], PD_Delivery_Schedule.Truck, IIf([PD_Delivery_Schedule].[Special Delivery Inst]>' ',[PD_Delivery_Schedule].[Special Delivery Inst],[PD_Mill_Start].[Special Delivery Inst]) AS [Special Delivery Inst], PD_Delivery_Schedule.[COD Over Ride], PD_Mill_Start.Batch, PD_Mill_Start.[Stain Grade/Paint Grade], PD_Mill_Start.Species, PD_Mill_Start.[Stave Core], PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Mill Start Sent], PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Mill Start Confirmed], PD_Mill_Start.[Last Of Door Desc], PD_Mill_Start.[Ship Via], IIf([PD_Mill_Start].[Job Name] Like '%glass%' Or [PD_Mill_Start].[Job Name] Like '%hinge%' Or [PD_Mill_Start].[Job Name] Like '%weather%' Or [PD_Mill_Start].[Job Name] Like '%molding%' Or [PD_Mill_Start].[Style] Like '%N/A%' Or [PD_Mill_Start].[Interior or Exterior] Like '%other%',[Batch Door Count],0) AS [Del Other Qty], IIf([Batch Jamb Count] Is Not Null,[Batch Jamb Count],0) AS [Del Jamb Qty], IIf([Batch Door Count] Is Null,0,IIf([PD_Mill_Start].[Interior or Exterior] Like '%case%' Or [Style] Like '%case%',0,[Batch Door Count]-[Del Other Qty])) AS [Del Door Qty]
FROM PD_Mill_Start LEFT JOIN PD_Delivery_Schedule ON PD_Mill_Start.[Order Number] = PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Order Number]
WHERE PD_Mill_Start.[Order Number]='350844'
ORDER BY PD_Mill_Start.[Order Number] DESC;
```

Error Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Del Other Qty'.

Comment: I would reduce the query down to one select item and see if that solves the issue. You then can add each piece back until it throws the error. Otherwise is IIF compatible in your version of sql-server? Not sure what version you are running.

Comment: [PD_Mill_Start].[Interior or Exterior]  - I'm not sure, but I think this might be the culprit.

Comment: Errr.... is this part of your  real code `IIf` ? If so, the syntax is `if`, not with 2 i's. Unless, it's syntax I'm not aware of.

Comment: @Fred-ii- iif is sql server 2012 and above

Comment: @Kritner Thanks for clarifying that up for me, *cheers*

Comment: @BillH. that is quite a long list of items in your select statement.  Start by commenting out "half" of the list, if it fails comment out more, if it succeeds comment out less.  It's a hell of a lot easier for you on your end to find it than us on our end without the schema :P

Comment: The query doesn't throw the error until I add the IIf statement back in, without it the query runs fine.

Comment: I am not sure that `IIF` allows the use of `or`

Comment: I removed all of the "or" statements and simplified it down to just the first "like" statement and still get the invalid column name error.

Comment: Whenever I get an invalid column name error, it always says what the invalid name is.   It looks like this:  `Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name 'Bucket Id'.`   Please update your post with the full error message.

Comment: @TabAlleman I added the error msg "Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Del Other Qty'." and it appears the the iif statement I included in my original post works correct .. its actually the last statement in the select that is throwing the error IIf([Batch Door Count] = ' ',0,IIf([PD_Mill_Start].[Interior or Exterior] Like '%case%' Or [Style] Like '%case%',0,[Batch Door Count]-[Del Other Qty])) AS [Del Door Qty"

Comment: Then it looks like @Kritner's answer is correct.   `Del Other Qty` isn't a real column in your table, it's an alias you created in your query.   You can't re-use it in the formula for another column in the same query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use "derived/aliased" columns in the select query in calculations within that same query... I don't know if those are the correct words, but consider:

```
declare @table table (val1 int, val2 int)

insert into @table (val1, val2)
values (5,10)

select 
    val1, -- 5
    val2, -- 10
    val1*val2 as val3, -- this works, 50
    val3+1 as val4 -- this does not work, you probably expect 51.
from @table
```

You ***can*** do this (among other things)

```
select val1, val2, val3, 
val3+1 as val4 -- this now works, returns 51
from (
    select 
        val1, 
        val2, 
        val1*val2 as val3, -- this works, 50
    from @table
) thingy
```

another option is:

```
select 
    val1,
    val2,
    val3,
    val3+1 as val4
from @table
cross apply (select val1 * val2 as val3) thing
```

Sorry I don't know the correct terminology for these concepts. The important part is you cannot use a "derived/aliased" column as part of a calculation within the same select query - which is what you're attempting to do in your query `[Batch Door Count]-[Del Other Qty]`.  If you refactor your query utilizing the ideas from above, you will no longer have your issue.  I'm trying to work on that now, but this query is quite unwieldy.

Comment: Thank you Kritner ... I rewrote it to do the math after the query and all is good!